# If my iPad is dead/switched off, will I still get a FaceTime missed call notification if someone tries to ring me?

Tags: notifications, facetime

If my iPad is out of battery/switched off when someone tries to FaceTime call me, will I get a missed call notification when I turn it back on? Because FaceTime uses WiFi, will the missed call be stored on Apple servers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd be notified of the FaceTime call you missed while your iOS device was switched off.